# Rails Request Uri Too Large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku, uri

I have a method in my app that accepts a CSV of several hundred of a users contacts phone numbers, varying in length, but up to several thousand characters long. Upon attempting to execute the method as:

`localhost:3000/getActivatedFriends/phoneNum1,phoneNum2,phoneNum3...phoneNum350...etc`

the error below appeared:

```
Request-URI Too Large

WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge
```

On my personal device, the number of characters in the CSV is 2868. How can I get around this limitation or perhaps set to unlimited length  in localhost and Heroku?

*request controller action:
(please ignore possible SQL injection as this is simply in developement)*

```
def getActivatedFriends
        @results = User.find_by_sql("SELECT 
                                                a.id
                                             ,  a.username
                                             ,  a.phoneNumber
                                             FROM users a
                                             WHERE phoneNumber in (" + params[:friends_phone_number_csv].to_s + ") and
                                                   removed = 0 and
                                                   is_user = 1;")

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: { friends_match: @results }}
        end         
    end
```

*rails route:*

```
get '/getActivatedFriends/:friends_phone_number_csv',
  to: 'requests#getActivatedFriends', via: 'post',
  constraints: { friends_phone_number_csv: /([0-9]+,?)+/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a POST request instead, that should fix the problem.

Comment: As you can see by the defined route: `get '/getActivatedFriends/:friends_phone_number_csv',
  to: 'requests#getActivatedFriends', via: **'post'**,
  constraints: { friends_phone_number_csv: /([0-9]+,?)+/ } ` I have already defined it as a post request...

Comment: Isn't this a get request forwarding to a post controller?  I think the problem you're having is related to maximum size of a get request.  Most browsers (and servers) have a maximum url length, if memory serves this is 2048 as implemented by IE.

Comment: How can I implement this? Can I bundle...?

Comment: why can't you just do: `post '/getActivatedFriends/:friends_phone_number_csv' ...`  Sorry if it seems like I'm pushing in this direction but you really should use a post instead of a get in this instance.

Comment: The problem is that I need it to be a get, because I need to retrieve data after the query has executed

Comment: Get and Post are the same as far as rails is concerned.  It's rest that's "broken" by what I'm suggesting.  If you want to be correct in terms of rest make it a post that "adds" friends, and returns a list.  Your request will have to change to pack data into the post body instead of the url.  Your post should be sent to `/getActivatedFriends` with a post variable containing the phone numbers.

Comment: Can you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332019/building-post-request-and-return-json-data